# Как восстановить или заменить ключ от android приложения в google play?

Tags: android, android-studio, криптография, google-play

Я потерял свой ключ **jks** и из-за этого не могу обновить приложение в *google play*.

Можно ли его как-то заменить или восстановить?

Comment: А почему не обращаетесь в службу поддержки?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Answer (score 5):

Ничего сделать нельзя. Создавайте новый ключ и выкладывайте новое приложение с новым пакетом.

Про приложение с утерянным ключом можно забыть навсегда. У Гугла вашего ключа нет и получить его никак нельзя