# Был утерян электронный ключ подписи приложения Android

Tags: android

Добрый день!

Был утерян ключ подписи - jks
Если мы знаем все данные этого ключа, Alias, пароль и все остальные данные.
Возможно ли воссоздать точно такой же ключ подписи?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как восстановить или заменить ключ от android приложения в google play?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722292/181100)

Comment: Впредь, что бы больше не потерять ключ используйте Google Play App Signing - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Answer (score 3):

## Нет.

Сам ключ **случаен**, его генерация не определяется вводимыми вами данными.

То, что вам известно, лишь **метаданные** (мол, чей ключ) и **пароль** от зашифрованного ключ-файла (чтобы имея только файл ключа нельзя было им воспользоваться; это стандартная мера безопасности для криптоключей, хранящихся в доступных третьим лицам файловых системах).